# Laravel applying search filers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a page which has a search box(input text) which takes a place name as input and returns all the nearby dealers.

I also happen to have filters (checkboxes) for all the brand

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              {!! Form::checkbox('filters',$bike_oem, false,['style'=>'padding-right:5px;']   ) !!} <span style="padding-left:5px;"></span>{{ $bike_oem }}
 </div>
```

How do I implement get the value of filter in my controller ?

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
              <input style="padding-right:5px;" name="Hyundai " type="checkbox" value="Y"> <span style="padding-left:5px;"></span>Hyundai 
</div>
```

This is how each filter appears in the page. Is the code correct to fetch the value in controller ? Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of checkbox in this way also(in controller)

```
public function myFunction(Request $request){
 if (isset($request['Hyundai']) && ($request['Hyundai'] == "on")) {
           $value = "Y";
  }
}
```

Comment: Prefect! Worked. Thanks!. You saved me a lot.

Comment: What is 'orderDelay' here ? am I missing something ? Please throw some light.

Comment: sorry , that was my mistake. I have edited now. just write your checkbox field name there i.e. "Hyundai" .

Comment: Hi Saurabh, there are many such filters keywords. Can I pickup anything from the URL ? When I select  a checkbox, the url is appended by /Hyundai=Y. Can it be made dynamic ?